# Python: Changing datatype of index from object to date time removes time (HH:MM:SS)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to upsample some data I have from daily to hourly. To do this I need to get the index in date time format, but I've become stuck due to the following issue.

I load my df in:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("DATA.CSV", index_col="DT")
df1.head(5)
```

[df1 example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sutty.png)

This looks fine, but the datatype is object and I need to convert to date time. So I tried:

```
df1.index = pd.to_datetime(df1.index)
df1.head(5)
```

Which does work in changing the datatype, but the index has now lost its time component:

[df1 after changing data type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z4Mf.png)

Would anyone please be able to advise how I could make the datatype datetime AND show the time? Does anyone know why the time disappears? Could it be because it's 00:00:00?

Comment: What is reason for `time` display?

Comment: @GJB : you need a string representation if you want timestamp in `df.index` , check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read the file as :

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("DATA.CSV")
```

then apply:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.set_index('Date')
```

replace `Date` column with the original date column name.

**Note:** this converts the index to string.

Another solution:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("DATA.CSV", index_col="DT", parse_dates=['DT'])
df1.index = df1.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: and also is necessary notify losing datetimeindex, because string index is created

Comment: Thanks to both anky_91 and Jezrael - much appreciated!